# Flash[:notice] if page.blank?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, notice, respond-to

I am having a search form on my index page that redirects to a page that shows all statuses with the params given by search. Now I want to put in a flash notice if the page is blank because the search param doesn't fit to any of my statuses. any idea?
greetz

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
@search = User.find('status', params[:status])

rediret_to page_path, notice: "Requested status is not available" if @search.present?
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be ok:

```
def index
  @statuses = Status.scope_to_retreive_statuses
  flash.now[:notice] = 'No statuses to display' if @statuses.empty?
end
```

More info about `flash` here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

Answer (score 0):

Put flash notice in else condition if searched object is nil.

```
def search_status
  @search = User.find_by_status(params[:status])
  if @search.present?
    // Respective action
  else
    flash[:notice] = 'Requested status is not available'
    rediret_to '/Index'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def search_status
  @search = User.find_by_status(params[:status])
  if !@search.present?
    flash[:notice] = 'Requested status not available'
    rediret_to '/Index'
  end
end
```